# Why does this operation always return 0

Tags: swift, operators

So I am making a app that calculates simple interest. Here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet var principle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var rate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var time: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var total: UILabel!
//@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
@IBAction func buttonTapped(AnyObject) {
    println("Calculate button tapped!")
    var principleInt: Int = principle.text.toInt()!
    var rateInt: Int = rate.text.toInt()! / 100
    var timeInt: Int = time.text.toInt()!
    var answer: Int = timeInt * rateInt * principleInt
    println(answer)
    var myString = String(answer)
    total.text = myString
}
```

But answer always returns 0. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using doubles or floats for calculating interest?

Comment: This function doesn't return anything at all. Are you asking why it sets the text to `"0"`? If so, can you print out what values are in the other three variables? Have you actually typed something in them? Is it interpreting what you typed as an integer properly? Is your rate >100, so `rateInt` won't be guaranteed to round down to `0`?

Comment: I have actually typed something in them and my rate is smaller than 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm willing to bet your problem is here:

```
var rateInt: Int = rate.text.toInt()! / 100
```

Let's say you entered `5` for the rate. So, you get the string `"5"`, convert that to the int `5`, divide by `100` and get `0`. Then you multiply that by any two other numbers and the result is `0`.

Why? Well, the whole point of integers is that they are numbers without fractional values.* See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) for more detail, but that should be enough to understand that `5/100` is a fractional value, and if you force Swift to put that into an integer, the best you could possibly get is `0` (or `1`).**

If you want to handle rates that aren't an even multiple of 100%, you probably want to set `rateInt` to an integer *without* dividing by 100, then set another variable, like `rateFraction` to a `double`, with the value `rateInt / 100.0`, then multiply that with the other two values, then (if desired) round and cast back to integer at the end.

---

<sub>* It's probably more accurate to say that the whole point of the integers is that they're an extension of the naturals to negative numbers. You can put that in terms of additive inverse, predecessor, closure over subtraction, or whatever. But for someone who doesn't even know what an integer is, "numbers without fractional values" is probably clearer.</sub>

<sub>** There are different rules that arguably make sense: round toward 0, round toward negative infinity, round to the nearest integer, with one of a few different special rules for `1/2`. But that hardly matters here; the fraction `5/100` is between `0` and `1`, so it's going to round to one of those two numbers if you try to force it to be an integer. The fact that it happens to be `0` in Swift, and almost every other programming language, isn't that important.</sub>

Comment: Can you tell me why it gives me 0 when I divide 5 by 100?

Comment: @jakesan700: Integers are numbers without fractions. 5 divided by 100 is the fraction `5/100` (or `1/20`). The closest integer to that is `0` (or `1`, depending on how you round), so you get `0`.

Comment: @abarnert how do I prevent this from rounding to 0 or 1? I want it's result to have decimal places

Comment: @Cherry_thia The answer already explains that: either don't divide by 100, so you have an integer from 0 to 100, or use a double or float instead of an int, so you have a floating-point number from 0.0 to 1.0.